# Can it fit the rim i have?

Tags: tire, wheels

Will a `26x1.50` or `26x1.25` slick fit on a rim that I now have with a measure on the tire `26x2.00` and the rims I have are `26inch bontrager AT-550`?

Comment: Compare the metric dimensions (stamped on the sidewalls) of the old and new tires.  A 26" tire will have a measurement such as 40-571, indicating tire width and rim diameter.  The second (larger) number needs to match between the two tires, the first does not.  (Unfortunately, "26-inch" rims vary in diameter by about half an inch, from one style to the next.)  As to width, the tire width should generally not be narrower than the outside width of the rim.

Answer (score 0):

The Bontrager AT-550 rim is a standard 26" mountain bike rim. A typical MTB 26" tire, including the narrower 1.25" should fit, yes.

You should compare the bead diameter on the original tire to the new tire.  it's the three digit number on the tire that matters.  Usually, for these tires, it would be 559mm.

You should make sure that the tire width is a minimum of 1/8" or 5mm wider than the width of the rim.